# How to make Firefox show Unicode characters of URL in Reader View mode?

Tags: firefox, unicode

If you want to copy Unicode characters from address bar as they are you should set this item in about:config to **true**: `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy`. But the problem is that Firefox doesn't show Unicode characters in their original form when reading a web page in Reader View. So if I copy the URL from Reader View I'll end up with something like this:
`https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D8%AF`
rather than this:
`https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/یونی‌کد`
Is there a workaround for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Workaround; two aliases in bash:

```
$ alias -p
...
alias urldecode='python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import unquote; print(unquote(sys.argv[1]))"'
alias urlencode='python3 -c "import sys; from urllib.parse import quote; print(quote(sys.argv[1]))"'

$ urldecode https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D8%AF
https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/یونی‌کد

$ urlencode https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/یونی‌کد
https%3A//fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D8%AF
```

Comment: More complex converters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python

Comment: Thanks but I'm not familiar with bash aliases. Please explain how to do that. BTW, I'm on windows 8.1

Comment: Three ways: install www.cygwin.com, run/install a pure Linux, and then: use WSL - aliases can then be set in a text-file named `.bash_aliases` in the home folder. The aliases then get initialized as you open a Terminal (most often a Bash-based command line).